# How to pull a collection of elements from XML document that has a namespace and schema

Tags: xml, linq, xpath

I am having never-ending problems trying to pull a collection of nodes from an XML document.  I've been playing with tens of examples of code here on StackOverflow, but I always get an empty result set back.  I am beginning to think this may be something to do with namespaces, but I don't seem to be able to find any simple examples to show me what I am doing wrong.  Here is the (simplified) XML file I am trying to access:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<pages
    xmlns="http://myurl.co.uk/xml/Pages.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.myurl.co.uk/xml/Pages.xsd Pages.xsd"
>
    <page token="A">
        <page1>P1</page1>
        <page2>P2</page2>
    </page>
    <page token="B">
        <page1>P1</page1>
        <page2>P2</page2>
    </page>
    <page token="C">
        <page1>P1</page1>
        <page2>P2</page2>
    </page>
</pages>
```

And the schema...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="http://myurl.co.uk/xml/Pages.xsd"
    targetNamespace="http://myurl.co.uk/xml/Pages.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
>
    <xs:element name="pages">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence">
                <xs:element name="page" type="PageType">
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="PageType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="page1" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="page2" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="token" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

And one of hundreds of code fragments I have unsuccessfully tried:

```
XDocument pageDoc = XDocument.Load( "Pages.xml" );
var a = pageDoc.Root.XPathSelectElements( "page" );
```

I am tearing my hair out with this.  If you can offer any help, I will try not to rip your arm of as I desperately snatch it.

Kind wishes ~ Patrick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(Server.MapPath(@"~\xml\test.xml"));

XmlNamespaceManager xmlnsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("def", "http://myurl.co.uk/xml/Pages.xsd");

XmlNodeList NodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/def:pages/def:page", xmlnsManager);

foreach (XmlNode node in NodeList)
{

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code.  I recognize this.  Is this the 'old' way of handling XML (i.e. pre XDocument, XElement, etc.)?  I tried it.  Sadly, it ran okay, but again found no records.  Perhaps I am missing something obvious here.  Argghhh - I am going mental with this.

Comment: This now works. Same as above - I had a stupid typo in the code. Doh!. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
 XDocument Xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\xxxxxxxx\XMLFile1.xml");
 XNamespace ns = "http://myurl.co.uk/xml/Pages.xsd";

 var ele = from data in Xdoc.Descendants(ns + "pages").Elements(ns+"page")
            select data;
```

OR

```
 var namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
                namespaceManager.AddNamespace("namespace", "http://myurl.co.uk/xml/Pages.xsd");
 var name = Xdco.XPathSelectElements("/namespace:pages/namespace:page", namespaceManager);
```

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I tried both of these.  The first one compiled and ran, but again found no records.  In the second example, I can't find a definition for Xdco.  Guess I am missing a using statement.

Comment: Finally... got the first one to work. I had a stupid typo in the code. Phew! Now I can have Christmas in peace. Thank you.

Comment: @Patrick Second one will also work you just need to define `namespace`to access elements .